# Dnn Rich Text(Text editor) template manager doesn't load

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I've been working with DNN for the past weeks and now it's finnaly time to make my project to the production server, but I found an issue.
In the default Rich Text we have a "Template" option, witch we can save html presets, saving them works fine. But when I try to open the list of templates, the small popup opens and stays forever loading, no error displayed.

[Ethernal loading image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meb4b.png)

I believe it's a config issue, since it works fine on my development eviroment. The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2(so, no IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool user to give permissions). Also I already gave permission to IIS_IUSRS and to IUSR.

If someone could help me, that would be awesome =)

Best Regards

Comment: Did you check in browser console? Is there any javascript error?

Comment: Yes, no JS errors found.

Answer (score 0):

do other dialogs fail as well, or just this one?

My guess is that the folder, which contains the templates, doesn't exist - or it does exist, but DNN doesn't know about it. So make sure you have it and that the the DNN files are synced with the DB (in the admin > files section)

Comment: I have the problem only when I try to open the list of templates, when I try to save them, everything goes right. I have saved some templates with this same component, and all went well. I think this excludes the "non-existing/unknown folder".

But about this last part, Files must be synced to the database? I went to admin -> file management and found the folder where the tamplates were suposed to be saved, and also the saved templates. Have I missundertood any part of your suggestion?

Comment: I believe your use case is still very unclear. A quick screen-cast showing the scenario which works, and the one which fails, would certainly help.

Comment: You wouldn't believe the stupid cause of this problem, it's called Internet Explorer.

I was testing on chrome in my enviroment, and on IE11 on the server enviroment, I have just installed chrome on the server and now the template manager works fine.